# Белье развешено или развешано?

Tags: суффиксы, причастия

Также назовите,  какой вариант является правильным: Не колючий, светло-синий,  по ветвям развешан иней. Но: Афиши уже  развешены.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Развешать - по разным местам, в пространстве - бельё развешано, иней развешан, афиши развешаны.

РАЗВЕСИТЬ1 - Разделить на части по весу. Р. муку.

Развесить2 -многозначное:

1. То же, что развешать (разг.)
2. Широко раскинуть, распустить. Береза развесила свои ветви. Развесить бельё в значении "широко раскинуть концами в стороны"-развесил на ветках Развесить уши (разг. ирон.) - доверчиво слушать, -аю, -аешь

Comment: Так что первый вариант - про иней нормативен,верен, а афиши развешены - разговорный.

Comment: А почему развешать - нейтральный стиль, а развесить - разговорный?

Comment: По Ожегову развешать - повесить по разным местам, в пространстве, но в живой речи не все различают значения слова и употребляют  в этом значении и "развесить", поэтому это употребление разговорное и значение слова помечено как разговорное в словарях.